# Is Hanuman worshiped independently of his association with Rama?

Tags: rama, hanuman

A search on Bard finds

> Panchmukhi Hanuman Temple, Karachi, Pakistan: This temple is dedicated to the five-faced Hanuman. It does not have an idol of Rama, as Hanuman is not always portrayed as being associated with Rama.

Is there scripture devoted to Hanuman without bringing in his association with Rama?